# Referencing a file using Document Root

Tags: php, linux

This code was previously working for me. But then GoDaddy moved me over to a Linux box and now it's not:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$connection = $path . '\mySite\scripts\connection.php';
include ($connection);

session_start();
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: include(/var/chroot/home/content/07/11347607/html\mySite\scripts\connection.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/07/11347607/html/mySite/scripts/administration/login.php on line 5
```

Obviously, I can read the error message, which says that the file doesn't exist. However, I have verified that the is indeed there (as it was before the Linux change), but maybe my code must not be working in a Linux file system context? I tried switching the `\` to `/` but this didn't solve anything.

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks!

EDIT:
I changed the `\` to `/`. This changed my error. I now get two errors:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/home/content/07/11347607/tmp/sess_7ner0g9kbgp5htc4bm7cleblb7, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /home/content/07/11347607/html/mySite/scripts/administration/login.php on line 8

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/07/11347607/html/mySite/scripts/administration/login.php:8) in /home/content/07/11347607/html/mySite/scripts/administration/login.php on line 8
success
Warning: Unknown: open(/home/content/07/11347607/tmp/sess_7ner0g9kbgp5htc4bm7cleblb7, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0
```

Here is the code in `connection.php` that I have been using successfully to connect:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $db_name);
if (!link) die("no connection");
```

Comment: Use forward slashes (`/`) on Linux. Actually, they'll work on Windows just fine too.

Comment: What @Carpetsmoker means is change `path\to\file` to `path/to/file`

Comment: Make sure the directory `/home/content/07/11347607/tmp` exists and is writeable by the web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everybody who commented and responded. After spending quite a while on three different tech support calls with GoDaddy, we finally figured out that the problem was on their end. No code changes required.

I'm really sorry to have wasted everybody's time. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this and make your path relatively.

```
$path = __DIR__;
$connection = $path . '\mySite\scripts\connection.php';
include ($connection);
```

Comment: You must  make your path relatively!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using:

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__);
$connection = $path . '/mySite/scripts/connection.php';
include_once($connection);
```

Forward slashes should work with Windows or Linux Boxes: [Reference](http://alanhogan.com/tips/php/directory-separator-not-necessary)

Your linux box may also be running a different version of PHP so you may need to modify your `connection.php` as well script.  Use PDO if this is a database connection! [PDO Tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338)